# How does one use AzureMfaProtocolProvider for technical profile without a "Submit" button

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Using Azure AD MFA technical profile with this document as a guide [Azure AD MFA technical profiles in custom policies - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-auth-technical-profile), the self-asserted technical profile works just fine. But instead of using a “submit” button to pass on the code, how does one submit the code without using a “submit” button, that is, after entering the last digit of the code a verification of the code and a logon attempt is made.
Would like to achieve this using AzureMfaProtocolProvider.

Comment: Hmm, haven't done this personally, but maybe a solution with Javascript is needed? Hide the Submit button with CSS and trigger it through Javascript?

Comment: @juunas - I agree! I would definitely approach this requirement with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript, once the 6char are detected, use the submit() function to submit the page.

Create your HTML/JS/CSS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#custom-page-content-walkthrough

Enable Javascript
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thanks you for answering